# Right click is not happening and element is getting clicked on the same tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium script to execute the following steps:

1. Launch the website - https://vusevapor.com/
2. Hit "I am 21+" button
3. Move to element devices.
4. Right-click on ciro complete kit.

The issue is that the right-click menu remains as is, and the element is getting clicked on the same page.

Here is my code:

```
//website
driver.get("https://vusevapor.com/");

//clicking on i am 21+ button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/aside/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/a[1]/span")).click();   

Thread.sleep(5000);
//xpath of devices menu

WebElement devices = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"store.menu\"]/nav/ul/li[2]/a/span"));

//move to element devices

Actions act = new Actions(driver);

act.moveToElement(devices).build().perform();

Thread.sleep(3000);

//xpath of ciro complete kit

WebElement ciroKit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"store.menu\"]/nav/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a/span"));


//right click on ciro complete kit 

//*****Issue********right click is happening but the element is getting clicked on the same tab and right click menu remains as is

act.contextClick(ciroKit).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
option 1:

```
act.contextClick(ciroKit).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

option 2-
Use Action and Robot class:

```
act.contextClick(ciroKit).build().perform();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Option 1 did not work but Option 2 worked.

Comment: Can you please help me understand why option 1 is not working? Your response will help me to understand this issue completely.

Comment: which chrome version your using?

Comment: My chrome version is 80.0.3987.116

Comment: Please have a look. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/aVx0_zc3rw0